# Why can't I modify one dictionary while iterating over another dictionary (get changed size error)?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, variable-assignment

I am confused as to why modifying one dictionary that has been created using another dictionary leads to a **RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration**:

```
def test(somedict):
    new = somedict
    for k,v in somedict.iteritems():
        new['test'] = new.pop(k)
    return new
```

---

```
>>>test(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    test(data[0])
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 3, in test
    for k,v in somedict.iteritems():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

**USE CASE:** I was trying to replace all the keys in a copy of the dictionary using a lookup table, and noticed that I cannot pop() keys out of the new dictionary that I am NOT iterating over.

I realize that using somedict.copy():

```
new = somedict.copy()
```

solves the problem. But I don't understand why this is illegal in python to begin with.

can someone explain what the difference is between new = somedict and new = somedict.copy()? Assigning variables doesn't mean that the data from which the new assignment is derived is also modified when the child variable is modified, as least that's what I thought.

Comment: _"Assigning variables doesn't mean that the data from which the new assignment is derived is also modified when the child variable is modified."_ Prepare to be surprised. Try running `a = {1:2}; b = a; b[1] = 3; print a`, and you'll see that modifying `b` also causes `a` to change.

Comment: I was very surprised! Time to review everything I've ever coded...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `new = somedict` does not actually mean that they are two seperate objects in memory.  They are in fact the same objects.

However when you use the `.copy()` you are now creating a new object in memory that allows you to manipulate it.

```
str_MemoryID = "Object {0:10} memory location is: {1}"
str_Contents = "Object {0:10} contents are: {1}"

test = {"one":1, "two":2}
new = test
new_copy = test.copy()

# printing the memory ID of the objects
print(str_MemoryID.format("test", id(test)))
print(str_MemoryID.format("new", id(new)))
print(str_MemoryID.format("new_copy", id(new_copy)))

print("\n")

# print the contents of the dictionaries

print(str_Contents.format("test", test))
print(str_Contents.format("new", new))
print(str_Contents.format("new_copy", new_copy))

print("\n")

# make a change to the "new" dictionary and let's see what happens
new['new_item'] = 3

print(str_Contents.format("test", test))
print(str_Contents.format("new", new))
print(str_Contents.format("new_copy", new_copy))

print("\n")

# make a change to the "new_copy" dictionary and let's see what happens
new_copy.popitem()

print(str_Contents.format("test", test))
print(str_Contents.format("new", new))
print(str_Contents.format("new_copy", new_copy))
```

gives the following output:

```
Object test       memory location is: 8606920
Object new        memory location is: 8606920
Object new_copy   memory location is: 8606856


Object test       contents are: {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
Object new        contents are: {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
Object new_copy   contents are: {'one': 1, 'two': 2}


Object test       contents are: {'one': 1, 'new_item': 3, 'two': 2}
Object new        contents are: {'one': 1, 'new_item': 3, 'two': 2}
Object new_copy   contents are: {'one': 1, 'two': 2}


Object test       contents are: {'one': 1, 'new_item': 3, 'two': 2}
Object new        contents are: {'one': 1, 'new_item': 3, 'two': 2}
Object new_copy   contents are: {'two': 2}
```

Comment: That is evident. Now if two objects are the same memory object and I update one and not the other, the assignments in these dictionaries are now different. The objects appear different on output, but I cannot iterate over them as if they were different objects. Why the inconsistency?

Comment: Wow - I've been writing python for years and I never realized this. If you create test = {"one":1, "two":2}, then assign new = test, then modify new, test is also changed AFTER you have created the link. Both are affected if you don't copy(). 

Excuse me while I go and review thousands of lines of code...

Comment: @MarcMaxson Python sometimes has those 'surprises'.  ;)

Comment: @MarcMaxson yep, assignment **is not** copying. This only matters for mutable objects, though.

Comment: So I see the same applies to lists too? But there is no list.copy() method. What am I supposed to do then? I feel like I'm suddenly a noob. I think I've been iterating over the values in a list and putting them into a new list that was empty to begin with, not a copy of the old one.

Comment: The `.copy()` method on `dicts` is something of an anomaly; most types do not have a similar method. What you would usually do is just use the type to make a copy: `listcopy = list(oldlist)`, `copydict = dict(olddict)`, and so on. In the case of lists you can also take a slice of the whole list: `listcopy = oldlist[:]`

Answer (score 2):

```
def test(somedict):
    new = somedict
    for k,v in somedict.iteritems():
        new['test'] = new.pop(k)
    return new
```

is equivalent to:

```
def test(somedict):
    for k,v in somedict.iteritems():
        somedict['test'] = somedict.pop(k)
    return somedict
```

because the statement `new = somedict` means that `new` is the same dictionary as `somedict`

In the loop, you are iterating over the key/value pairs of `somedict`, and you are popping elements of `somedict`, so the dictionary's size is changed, which results in

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration:
```

By using `new = somedict.copy()`, you create a new copy of the dictionary, so modifying `new` will not modify `somedict` and you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In short, lookup reference semantics vs value semantics to understand Python's behavior.